# How to save checkboxes from gridview into a session?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have 2 gridviews. One for the shop and another for the shopping cart. For the gridview in the shop  I have checkboxes next to each product for the user to select and add to their cart. This will then bring them to the shopping cart page which will have a go back button. How do I create a session that will keep all the selected products so that when the user clicks back the products they selected before is still selected.

Gridview for Shop:

```
            <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Id" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Price" DataFormatString="{0:c2}" HeaderText="Price" SortExpression="Price" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Add To Cart">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="cbAdd" runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
```

Comment: You can always save the datasource of your gridview to the session.  Get that data in the Form Load event and then in the OnRowDataBound for the gridview simply loop through and check any items that are checked in the source.

Answer (score 0):

You could store your ID values when the user checks the box. And then on page load when the data row is bound, you can use that list of stored IDs to re-check the boxes. For example see below:

Add hidden field to store IDs:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenSelectedRows" runat="server" />
```

Add the OnRowDataBound event to GridView:

```
OnRowDataBound="MyGridView_RowDataBound"
```

Add client side javascript code:

```
function getHiddenSelectedRows() { return $get("<%= this.HiddenSelectedRows.ClientID %>"); };    

var selectedRows = [];

function rowCheckedChanged(sender){       

        if (sender.checked) {
    //Find your row's ID value to use later
            selectedRows.push($("#" + sender.id)[0].parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.cells[1].innerHTML);
            getHiddenSelectedRows().value = selectedRows;
        } else {
            var index = selectedRows.indexOf($("#" + sender.id)[0].parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.cells[1].innerHTML);
            if (index > -1) {
                selectedRows.splice(index, 1);
                getHiddenSelectedRows().value = selectedRows;
            }
        }
    };
```

Change server side code to the generated event code:

```
    protected void MyGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> selectedRows = this.HiddenSelectedRows.Value.Split(',').ToList();
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            if (selectedRows.Contains(e.Row.Cells[1].Text))
            {
                CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("cbSelect");
                chk.Checked = true;
            }
        }

    }
```